# Shopify Route Error: undefine shopify_api_[resource]_path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify-app

Currently I am learning to create a Shopify custom app. I am working on metafields. A metafield can be created by

```
@metafield = ShopifyAPI::Metafield.new()
```

In form view, I use

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @metafield do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

The form requires me to define `shopify_api_metafields_path` etc.

Is there a way to define prefix `shopify_api` to my routes `resources :metafields` without adding `ShopifyApi::` module to my controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up with solution by defining a model `Metafield` which inherit from `ShopifyAPI::Metafield` and then, I define `@metafield = Metafield.new` instead of `@metafield = ShopifyAPI::Metafield.new`

By this way, it will be easier to manage later and it allow us to synchronize data table as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
resources :shopify_api_metafields, controller: :metafields
```

Which will give you:

```
    shopify_api_metafields GET    /shopify_api_metafields(.:format)               metafields#index
                           POST   /shopify_api_metafields(.:format)               metafields#create
 new_shopify_api_metafield GET    /shopify_api_metafields/new(.:format)           metafields#new
edit_shopify_api_metafield GET    /shopify_api_metafields/:id/edit(.:format)      metafields#edit
     shopify_api_metafield GET    /shopify_api_metafields/:id(.:format)           metafields#show
                           PATCH  /shopify_api_metafields/:id(.:format)           metafields#update
                           PUT    /shopify_api_metafields/:id(.:format)           metafields#update
                           DELETE /shopify_api_metafields/:id(.:format)           metafields#destroy
```